# Eclipse ide displays unnecessarily characters

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I dont want that red circled characters.
what to do?
I tried every possible solution I could

Comment: Those are White space . You have enabled "Show Whitespace Characters". Which is Left to debug Button in tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what's turned on in the Toolbar. You've turned on the showing of whitespace. Turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

As the other comments have said, you have `Show Whitespace Characters` on: here is your screenshot updated with an arrow pointing to the button to change it:

[image]